# Visual Studio Team Services FTP upload output of npm run build:prod

Tags: node.js, ftp, azure-devops

Using the CI stack builder in Visual Studio Team Services I was able to do an FTP upload from a repository and I was able to separately run npm install and npm run build:prod - however how do I join these two?

I want to run:

1. npm install
2. npm run build:prod
3. FTP upload the results of step 2

The problem I'm having is I have no idea how to access the results of the build command as the FTP command is asking which path to upload and only lets me choose existing paths in my repository.

Edit: When I run the build command on a local machine it creates a folder 'dist' in the root with the build output and I want to upload this output using FTP to a server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to specify the dist folder related path of source directory (e.g. XXX\1\s)

For example:
[image]
[image]